# Why my SQL response is undefined?(using mysql2/promise)

Tags: node.js, promise, mysql2

i want to pick my mysql response.

this is my code.

```
let [isTrue] = await conn.query("select user_key, isvalid from auth where user_key = ?", [user_key]);
console.log(isTrue);
```

This response was `[ TextRow { user_key: '123445', isvalid: 1 } ]`

That's good. But i want to get a value of user_key.
So I typed this code.

`console.log(isTrue.user_key)`

But this result was only `undefined`

How can i get a value of user_key??

Comment: As the response is an Array of Objects, you have to loop over isTrue or isTrue[0].user_key to get the first results.

Comment: @hathija Gotcha!, Thank you for comment. You're right. I got a correct response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of "await conn.query" use like this "await query".

Example

```
const mysql = require('mysql'); // or use import if you use TS
const util = require('util');
const conn = mysql.createConnection({host:"localhost", user:"root", password:"root", database:"test"});

// node native promisify
const query = util.promisify(conn.query).bind(conn);

(async () => {
  try {
    //const rows = await query('select count(*) as count from users ');
    //console.log(rows);
    var user_key = 1;
     const [isTrue] = await query("select id,name from users where id = ?", [user_key]);
    console.log(isTrue.name);

  }
    catch(err) {
    throw new Error(err)
    }
  finally {
    conn.end();
  }
})();
```

Comment: isTrue[0].user_key to successfully got a response. But I didn't know util.promisify things. Thanks Senthil!